# How to throw an error when no data exists on trigger

Tags: sql, asp.net, .net, oracle

I want to throw an error when there is no data found on trigger,so i used following trigger.It worked when no data found first time,after this when data prsents it is not working and no results happening.Any idea on this issue

```
    create or replace 
    trigger testtrigger
    after INSERT OR UPDATE 
    on T1
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
     SELECT t_power
        INTO t_power_trg
        FROM t3
        WHERE UPPER(t3.NAME) LIKE ('%' || UPPER(:NEW.INFO) || '%'); 
        EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'-------------Selected  model is  not present (info(2))-------------');
  SELECT refer_power
        INTO refer_power_trg
        FROM t3
        WHERE UPPER(t3.NAME) LIKE ('%' || UPPER(:NEW.TAR2) || '%'); 
        EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'-------------Selected  reference is  not present (info(2))-------------');

      UPDATE t_master
      SET 
       Master_pwr=t_power_trg where firstname='Z'
    END IF;
    END
```

Comment: "after this when data prsents it is not working and no results happening.Any idea on this issue" what does that mean?

Comment: when model presents,it is not working

Comment: Is this your whole trigger? What is that extra `END IF;` doing there? And what's the purpose of the `UPDATE t_master` statement? Is it supposed to ever run? because it won't currently.

Comment: Update staement should run everytime in to a master table which is not happening

Comment: @kfinity why it won't currently????

Comment: since i post snippet there may look syntax issues but, it is not preesnt infact

Answer (score 2):

There are some SYNTAX issue in your code, check out the below code. Hope it will make sense to your requirement.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER testtrigger
    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON T1
    FOR EACH ROW 
    DECLARE 
      t_power_trg T3.T_POWER%TYPE;
    BEGIN
    SELECT t_power
      INTO t_power_trg
      FROM t3
     WHERE UPPER(t3.NAME) LIKE ('%' || UPPER(:NEW.INFO) || '%');

    UPDATE t_master
       SET Master_pwr=t_power_trg
     where firstname='Z';

    EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
         RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'-------------Selected  model is  not present (info(2))-------------');
    END;
```

Comment: also, I shifted the UPDATE statement before EXCEPTION, because that will the use case for you, as I understand.

Comment: but i have few other select satatements also ,if we give exception below,how to give specific exception rather than generic one

Comment: Then I think you have to update your question in details. I suggested and corrected your code that you shared, so please update other part of code or at least dummy codes

Comment: In this case, your first UPDATE will be before first exception. Within first exception use don't put the RAISE exception otherwise further SQL will not execute. So you have to use 2nd BEGIN END within first exception and then put your 2nd SELECT and handle the exception in 2nd BEGIN END

Comment: If 1st SELECT statement return the value then you want to perform UPDATE-1, if no value then it goes to exception and there again you want to run 2nd SELECT if 2nd SELECT statement returns the rows then you want to perform UPDATE-2 else you want to throw the error using RAISE. Is am correct.

Answer (score 1):

This is a function, you could add a step just before your loop to capture the count of case you want to see

like this:

```
if ((select count(*)
       FROM t3
      WHERE UPPER(t3.NAME) LIKE ('%' || UPPER(:NEW.INFO) || '%')) < 1
    ) then
SET @error = '-------------Selected  model is  not present (info(2))-------------';
end if;
```

Comment: THe question is about oracle, not SQL server.

Comment: My bad! I tought this was a function, didnt notice that trigger was not the name of your function but an actual function